# DJI Mavic Mini Specs

Tags: quadcopters, camera, dji-mavic-mini

There are some specifications I was wondering about the DJI Mavic Mini.

First of all, is there a minimum or maximum temperature the drone can operate at?

What is the capacity and C rating on the battery?

Does the Mini support ActiveTrack?

What is the maximum range of the drone, either straight up or in one direction, *taking into account battery life*?

What is the maximum payload of the drone (how much weight can it carry)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> First of all, is there a minimum or maximum temperature the drone can operate at?

0° to 40°C (32° to 104°F)

> What is the capacity and C rating on the battery?

Capacity is 2400 mAh; C rating not given, as the battery is matched to the drone - but they list the charging power as 24W and the discharge rate is often higher than the charge rate.

> Does the Mini support ActiveTrack?

Apparently not; from the user manual:

> Mavic  Mini  supports  QuickShots  Intelligent  Flight  Mode. QuickShots  shooting  modes  include  Dronie,  Rocket,  Circle,  and Helix.

No mention of ActiveTrack, you would expect they would advertise the feature if present.

> What is the maximum range of the drone, either straight up or in one direction, taking into account battery life?

You'll need to do some maths depending on what exact flight profile you want, but DJI give a few helpful numbers:

- Flight endurance: 30 minutes at 14 kph
- Controller range: 2.4 GHz: 2000 m (MIC/CE), 5.8 GHz: 500 m (CE)
- Max Ascent Speed:  4 m/s (S Mode)
- Max Descent Speed :3 m/s (S Mode)
- Max Speed: 13 m/s (S Mode)

> What is the maximum payload of the drone (how much weight can it carry)?

Take-off weight is 249 g; I doubt DJI warrant the aircraft for any payload.

Sources:

- [Mavic Mini - Specifications - DJI](https://www.dji.com/uk/mavic-mini/specs) *(Accessed 2021-04-04)*
- [Mavic Mini User Manual v1.2](https://dl.djicdn.com/downloads/Mavic_Mini/v1.2/Mavic_Mini_User_Manual_v1.2_en.pdf) *(Accessed 2021-04-04)*